# List of IDE's for the Raspberry Pi

Tags: ide, pi-store

Is anybody currently maintaining a definitive list of IDE's that work with the Raspberry Pi? If not, can anyone supply a list of general-purpose IDE's (such as [Aptana Studio 3](http://www.aptana.com/)), and language specific IDE's (think of [IDLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE_%28Python%29)) for the Pi?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**General Purpose**

- [Adafruit Web IDE](http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2013/01/08/raspberry-pi-webide-update-to-0-3-0-debug/)
- [Lazarus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazarus_%28IDE%29) (just pull it from repository)
- [fpGUI](http://fpgui.sourceforge.net) ([Pi version](http://www.turbocontrol.com/easyfpgui.htm))
- [Code::Blocks IDE](http://store.raspberrypi.com/projects/codeblocks)

**Language Specific**

- [IDLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE_%28Python%29)

Comment: This is was made community wiki by me - this list should be updated constantly

Answer (score 4):

**General Purpose**

- Vim

While Vim by itself is a standalone text-editor(powerful one at that), it can support the features of an IDE. If I needed an IDE-like environment, this is the route that I would go simply because Vim is my favorite editor(for good reasons).

If you want more detail on turning Vim into an IDE, I found these links for you. Hope they're of some help:
https://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_Vim_like_an_IDE
http://haridas.in/vim-as-your-ide.html

Comment: Two great plugins for vim are *taglist*: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273 which provides a togglable, clickable sidebar index of functions/classes/methods/etc and will work with a bunch of different languages (at the same time, too) and *neocomplcache* http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2620 which does popup autocompletion, also for a bunch of languages.  There are a few other autocomplete plugins, "omnicppcomplete" is very popular.  If you are using X, the GUI vim (`gvim`) is a bit of an improvement and more mouse friendly in that context.

Answer (score 1):

[Xojo](http://www.xojo.com) does not run on the Pi, but it can create apps for Raspberry Pi (and Windows, OS X, Linux, web and iOS).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these RAD IDEs which run fine on Pi:

- [**Lazarus**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazarus_%28IDE%29) (just pull it from repository)
- [**fpGUI**](http://fpgui.sourceforge.net) ([Pi version](http://www.turbocontrol.com/easyfpgui.htm))

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it yet, but there's also [Code::Blocks IDE](http://store.raspberrypi.com/projects/codeblocks) on the Pi Store.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Lazarus you may also install and run Free Pascal on its own on Raspbian. It has a nice text-mode IDE. See http://www.elinux.org/Free_Pascal_on_RPi for details.